# Como funciona os loops e variáveis no jekyll?

Tags: ruby, loop, jekyll

Quando eu comparo no if se o `post.category` é como se não existisse a variável post que está no for mais quando eu coloco `{{post.category}}` ele imprime o nome. É como se no `if` ele não existisse mais se eu colocar `site.post.category` no if pega todos os valores.

O problema é que eu quero pegar o post corrente para comparar se é aquela categoria. Quero listar os posts pela categoria.

```html
<div class="posts">
  {% for post in site.posts %} 
    {% if post.category == Eventos %}
      <hr />
      <div class="post">
        <h1 class="post-title">
          <a href="{{ site.url }}{{post.url}}">
            {{ post.title }} 
          </a>
        </h1>
        <span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }} / {{ post.category }}</span>
        {{ post.excerpt }}
        <h6><a href="{{ site.url }}{{post.url}}">Leia mais...</a></h6>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sintaxe do loop está correta, ajuste o `if` para:

```
{% if post.category == "Eventos" %}
```

Comment: Que simples, muito obrigado @luciorubeens

Comment: Se a resposta foi aceita como correta, marque como "melhor resposta", por favor.